# Requesting features where expression result equals a given variable

Tags: pyqgis, qgsexpression, qgsfeaturerequest

I want to get the features of a layer, where the evaluated expression equals an already evaluated expression. Can I somehow do this directly using `layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(expr == other_expr))` or do I need to iterate over the whole layer first and evaluate the expressions inside the loop and do a test against the results?

Hard to explain in words, so here is a code that hopefully makes it understandable:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
firstfeat = layer.getFeature(1)
expr = QgsExpression('$geometry') # can be any expression, a field, a calculation, a geometry or just anything

fexpr_context = QgsExpressionContext()
fexpr_context.setFeature(firstfeat)
fexpr_context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(layer))
fexpr_result = expr.evaluate(fexpr_context)
print('First Features Expression-Result: ' + str(fexpr_result))

# can I somehow directly only request the features that meet my criteria?
matches = []
for feat in layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(expr == fexpr_result)): # obviously not this way
    matches.append(feat.id())
print(matches)
    
# or am I forced to go this way, iterating over the whole layer and testing against the result?
matches2 = []
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    expr_context = QgsExpressionContext()
    expr_context.setFeature(feat)
    expr_context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(layer))
    expr_result = expr.evaluate(expr_context)
    #print(expr_result)
    #if expr_result == fexpr_result: # no idea why this does not work
    #    matches2.append(feat.id())
    if str(expr_result) == str(fexpr_result): # and I need to convert to a string first..
        matches2.append(feat.id())
print(matches2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your example, for getting all features with the same geometry, you just have to change it to wkt so the comparaison is a simple equals.

like so
`QgsExpression(f"{expr.expression()} = '{fexpr_result}'")`

```python
layer = iface.activeLayer()
firstfeat = next(layer.getFeatures())
expr = QgsExpression('geom_to_wkt($geometry)') # can be any expression, a field, a calculation, a geometry or just anything

fexpr_context = QgsExpressionContext()
fexpr_context.setFeature(firstfeat)
fexpr_context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(layer))
fexpr_result = expr.evaluate(fexpr_context)
print('First Features Expression-Result: ' + str(fexpr_result))

# can I somehow directly only request the features that meet my criteria?
matches = []
new_expression = QgsExpression(f"{expr.expression()} = '{fexpr_result}'")
print(new_expression.expression()) # -> geom_to_wkt($geometry) = 'Point (357000.69953666 5318398.83947228)'


for feat in layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(new_expression)):
    matches.append(feat.id())
print(matches) # -> [7, 8, 9, 10]
    
# or am I forced to go this way, iterating over the whole layer and testing against the result?
matches2 = []
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    expr_context = QgsExpressionContext()
    expr_context.setFeature(feat)
    expr_context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(layer))
    expr_result = expr.evaluate(expr_context)
    #print(expr_result)
    #if expr_result == fexpr_result: # no idea why this does not work
    #    matches2.append(feat.id())
    if str(expr_result) == str(fexpr_result): # and I need to convert to a string first..
        matches2.append(feat.id())
print(matches2) # -> [7, 8, 9, 10]
```